# jQuery US Map plugin - add unique .html per clicked-state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have successfully implemented U.S. Map jQuery plugin via: http://newsignature.github.io/us-map/#usage-style-options

It works great, and I even customized size, state colors and hover colors. The current problem is, once a state is clicked the plugin is just setup to display the state ID *eg*: click Virginia and you get 'VA' under results -- **I need to add unique HTML for each state's results, not just the state ID that I just clicked.. Any suggestions?**

It's base configuration is:

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NewSignature/us-map/master/lib/raphael.js">
```

And:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 350px; height: 250px;"></div>
<div id="clicked-state"></div>
```

and:

```
$('#map').usmap({
  // The click action
  click: function(event, data) {
    $('#clicked-state')
      .text('You clicked: '+data.name)
      .parent().effect('highlight', {color: '#C7F464'}, 2000);
  }
});
```

**Update via Rory's suggestion:**

```
 var stateData = {
     VA: { fullName: 'Virginia' }
    // other states' data...
    },
  click: function(event, data) {
    $('#clicked-state')
        // .text('You clicked: '+data.name)
        .text('You clicked: ' + stateData[data.name].fullName) // = "Virginia
        .parent().effect('highlight', {color: '#C7F464'}, 2000);
  }
});
```

Comment: The example there is to just show you how to derive the clicked state's name value.  What you do with that value is really up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of the data you want to display, you could store it in an object, keyed by the name of the state. Here is a basic example, showing how to extend the information to include the full name of the state:

```
var stateData = {
    VA: { fullName: 'Virginia' }
    // other states' data...
}

// in map settings:
click: function(event, data) {
    $('#clicked-state')
        .text('You clicked: ' + stateData[data.name].fullName) // = "Virginia
        .parent().effect('highlight', { color: '#C7F464' }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Yeah I am seeking to display images and a small amount of text copy per state.

Comment: This method would work for that, you would just need to add those properties to each state entry.

Comment: I see what your saying, but getting a conflict with this method! error: 'stateData is not defined!!"

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: stateData is not defined

Comment: It sounds like you may be declaring it out of scope. It's difficult to tell without seeing your code

Comment: Well,,, I have it right next to it's use - I updated the code above!